# A good Code snippet tool or plugin for Word documents?

Tags: plugins, ms-word, openoffice.org, code-snippets, openoffice-writer

Does anyone know of a good tool or plugin that enables Microsoft Word or OpenOffice Writer to add code snippets to a document in a clean manner?

I'm not sure if such a plug-in even exists, so redirecting me to any other tool that can help me would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you want a little more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply type out the snippet in Visual Studio and then copy paste it into word. It preserves all the code formatting.

The only other thing I do is change the font to Consolas.

Answer (score 0):

I love codekeep for VS.. But it's only available for VS

Answer (score 0):

Snip-It Pro is a stand alone code snippet tool that works with word or open office. It docks to the side of the screen and snippets can be drag dropped into any application. It has syntax highlighting too.

disclaimer: It's my product :)